# How can I make my DB images be displayed in the table?

Tags: php, blob

My table at the moment is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAL09.jpg

The images go directly into the DB, so there isn't any file in the server for the images to go to be stored.

Select3.php:

```
<?php  
 $db_host        = 'localhost';
 $db_user        = 'root';
 $db_pass        = '';
 $db_database    = 'crc'; 
 $output = ''; 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pulseiras ORDER BY ref ASC ");
    $result->execute();     
$output .= '  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="10%">REF</th> 
                 <th width="25%">Nome</th> 
                 <th width="25%">Preço</th>  
                 <th width="25%">Imagem</th> 
            </tr>';  
 if (count($result) > 0)   
{  
 for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){ 
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td>'.$row["ref"].'</td>  
                  <td class="nome" data-ref1="'.$row["ref"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["nome"].'</td>  
                  <td class="preco" data-ref2="'.$row["ref"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["preco"].'</td> 
                  <td class="imagem" data-ref3="'.$row["ref"].'" contenteditable><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imagem'] ).'"/></td> 
                 <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-ref5="'.$row["ref"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">X</button></td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '  
       <tr>  
            <td></td>  
            <td id="nome" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="preco" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="imagem" contenteditable></td>    
       </tr>  
  ';  
}  
else  
{  
     $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                 </tr>';  
}  
$output .= '</table>  
     </div>';  
echo $output;  
?>
```

Image type is BLOB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: var_dump your query then come back and tell us what's in `$row['imagem']`. Or better yet, what IS the value of that?

Comment: The value of that, is the binary code of the image in the DB. @Fred-ii-

Comment: see if you get anything out of http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: No, nothing as happened. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to embed the image data directly into the html? A more common practice with blobs is to serve them from a separate page, which you then include as links in your html. This gives you browser caching functionality etc...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, if I do it the way you are telling me, will the images still appear in the table? Or only the link will appear? @Vrac

Comment: The images will appear. I'll write up an answer in a few minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I did this was in C# so I don't have any PHP lying around, but here is the basic idea in pseudocode:

A separate page servers the blob, call it getblob.php, with whatever parameters like getblob.php?blogname=myblob.jpg:

```
select blob from blobtable where name='myblob.jpg'
execute, fetch, etc...

set mime type = image/jpeg
do some buffering here if the blobs are big
echo $blob
```

In your html:

```
<img src='getblob.php?blobname=myblob.jpg'/>
<img src='getblob.php?blobname=myotherblob.png'/>
etc....
```

This allows the browser to cache the images individually, allows you to do buffering if the blobs are big, is much faster as there is no encoding, doesn't leave you with massive html pages with embedded base64 strings, is portable as the blobs can easily be linked into whatever other pages you want them in, allows a plugin to execute just the blob url if it's a pdf for example, etc...

Edit to add a php example from some site: [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/).